# Query providing different results on Cosmos (vs Pure Mongo)

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I have a Mongo collection which has this document structure:-

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5e5f1dfc325d4018302293"),
    "status" : "PENDING",
    "workflowJourney" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d5e5f1dfc325d401830229c"),
            "workflowDate" : ISODate("2019-08-22T09:23:41.491Z"),
            "workflowType" : "Email",
            "workflowDescription" : "Email sent to Joe Bloggs",
            "workflowRecipient" : {
                "employeeNumber" : "12345",
                "firstName" : "Joe",
                "surname" : "Bloggs",
                "emailAddress" : "joe.blogs@example.com"
            },
            "workflowSubject" : "Invoice Approval Required (2112)",
            "workflowHtmlContent" : "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitiona..."
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d5e5f1dfc325d401830229d"),
            "workflowDate" : ISODate("2019-08-22T09:23:41.507Z"),
            "workflowType" : "Email",
            "workflowDescription" : "Email sent to Jane Bloggs",
            "workflowRecipient" : {
                "employeeNumber" : "56789",
                "firstName" : "Jane",
                "surname" : "Bloggs",
                "emailAddress" : "jane.bloggs@example.com"
            },
            "workflowSubject" : "Invoice Approval Required (2112)",
            "workflowHtmlContent" : "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitiona..."
        }
    ],
    "approvals" : [],
    "__v" : 1
}
```

I'm trying to create a query which will get a single workflowJourney. At the point of executing the query, I will already know the _id of both the main document and the workflowJourney subdocument, so I could use either/both of of these in my query.

The issue is, for this development project we are using Azure Cosmos and the query that I would expect to work is giving strange results.

If I run this in pure Mongo:-

```
db.getCollection('Invoices').find(
 {"workflowJourney._id": ObjectId("5d5e5fd907ba93320cc54198")},
 {"workflowJourney.$": 1.0}
);
```

I get this nice result back:-

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5e5f1dfc325d4018302293"),
    "workflowJourney" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d5e5f1dfc325d401830229d"),
            "workflowDate" : ISODate("2019-08-22T09:23:41.507Z"),
            "workflowType" : "Email",
            "workflowDescription" : "Email sent to Jane Bloggs",
            "workflowRecipient" : {
                "employeeNumber" : "56789",
                "firstName" : "Jane",
                "surname" : "Bloggs",
                "emailAddress" : "jane.bloggs@example.com"
            },
            "workflowSubject" : "Invoice Approval Required (2112)",
            "workflowHtmlContent" : "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitiona..."
        }
    ]
}
```

Running the same query in Azure Cosmos (database contains the same data), I get this:-

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5e5f1dfc325d4018302293"),
    "workflowJourney" : [ 
        {}, 
        {}
    ]
}
```

So, no useful results. I know that Cosmos DB is more of a Mongo emulator rather than a pure implementation. But I guess what I am trying to achieve is a fairly common scenario; I wonder if anyone has any suggestions on how I could re-write my query to get the result I need?

Many thanks
Glen

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I've achieved what I need to do by doing the filtering from the Node level instead. I guess the filter queries are really designed for returning entire documents rather than filtering information from within a single document.

Example:-

```
router.get('/emailPreview/:invoiceId/:workflowJourneyItemId', (req, res, next) => {
  Invoice.findOne({ "_id": req.params.invoiceId })
  .then(invoice => {

    if(invoice) {
      const emailHtml = invoice.workflowJourney.filter((item) => {
        return item.id === req.params.workflowJourneyItemId;
      })[0].workflowHtmlContent;

    res.status(200).set('Content-Type', 'text/plain').send(emailHtml);
    } else {
      res.status(404).json({ Error: 'Email not found'});
    }

  }).catch(err => {
     res.status(404).json({ Error: 'Email not found'});
  })
});
```